# asyncio + aiohttp: overlapping IO with sleeping

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

When all coroutines are waiting, asyncio listens for events to wake them up again. A common example would be `asyncio.sleep()`, which registers a timed event. In practice an event is usually an IO socket ready for receiving or sending new data.

To get a better understanding of this behaviour, I set up a simple test: It sends an http request to localhost and waits for the response. On localhost, I've set up a flask server which waits for 1 second before responding. After sending the request, the client sleeps for 1 second, then it awaits the response. I would expect this to return in rougly a second, since both my program and the server should sleep in parallel. But it takes 2 seconds:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        # this http request will take 1 second to respond
        async with session.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/") as response:

            # yield control for 1 second
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            # wait for the http request to return
            text = await response.text()
            return text

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

start = perf_counter()
results = loop.run_until_complete(main())
stop = perf_counter()

print(f"took {stop-start} seconds") # 2.01909
```

**What is asyncio doing here, why can't I overlap waiting times ?**

I'm not interested in the specific scenario of HTTP requests, aiohttp is only used to construct an example. Which is probably a bit dangerous: This could be related to aiohttp and not asyncio at all.

Actually, I expect this to be the case (hence the question title about both asyncio and aiohttp).
My first intuition was that the request is maybe not sent before calling `asyncio.sleep().` So I reordered things a bit:

```
# start coroutine
text = response.text()

# yield control for 1 second
await asyncio.sleep(1)

# wait for the http request to return
text = await text
```

But this still takes two seconds.

Ok, now to be really sure that the request was sent off before going to sleep, I added `print("incoming")` to the route on the server, before it goes to sleep. I also changed the length of sleeping time to 10 seconds on the client. The server prints incoming immediately after the client is run. The client takes 11 seconds in total.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("incoming")
    time.sleep(1)
    return 'done'
```

Since the HTTP request is made immediately, the server has definitely sent off an answer before the client wakes up from `asyncio.sleep().` It seems to me that the socket providing the HTTP request should be ready as soon as the client wakes up. But still, the total runtime is always an addition of client and server waiting times.

Am I misusing asyncio somehow, or is this related to aiohttp after all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one second happens in server is performed in `async with session.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/") as response:`.

The http request finishes before you get this `response` object.

You can test it by:

```
...
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        start = perf_counter()
        # this http request will take 1 second to respond
        async with session.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/") as response:
            end = perf_counter()
            print(f"took {end-start} seconds to get response")
            # yield control for 1 second
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            # wait for the http request to return
            text = await response.text()
            return text
...
```

And btw you can surely overlap this waiting time, as long as you have another running coroutine.

Comment: oh that makes sense. But then I don't understand the design of aiohttp. If they already wait for a response in the "async with session.get", why do I have to wait for the response.text() again ? It's in the example on their server: https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Btw, I already wondered why the example didn't have to wait for the response status. Your answer explains that :)

Comment: Yeah I cannot understand that somehow. I think there are two reasons. First, `await res.text()` is reading content from a stream, actually the behavior depends on OS. I've heard that Windows supports real asynchronous data transporting, although I've never checked it by myself. So in this case, it makes sense. Another reason is to keep consistence: all perations should be coroutine.

Comment: @lhk `session.get()` gets the _head_ of the response, which is enough to tell e.g. the status code and the characteristics of the response. `response.text()` reads the _body_ of the response, which can take additional time if the body is sufficiently long.

Answer (score 0):

Your testing code has three awaits (two explicit and one hidden in `async with`) *in series*, so you don't get any parallel waiting. The code that tests the scenario you describe is something along the lines of:

```
async def download():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/") as response:
            text = await response.text()
            return text

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # have download start "in the background"
    dltask = loop.create_task(download())
    # now sleep
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # and now await the end of the download
    text = await dltask
```

Running *this* coroutine should take the expected time.